# How to send image and data (like name , age, id, gender) together from dotnet core webapi controller to angular front end and use it in the frontend

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

How to send image and data (like name , age, id, gender) together from dotnet core webapi to angular front end and use it  . Here is how i saved the product to backend at once.

```
addNewProduct(productToAdd: any) {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('photo', productToAdd.photo, productToAdd.photoName);//Here is the product photo 
    formdata.append('name', productToAdd.name);
    formdata.append('description', productToAdd.description);
    formdata.append('price', productToAdd.price);
    formdata.append('isInStock', productToAdd.isInStock)
    return this._http.post(BASE_URL + 'product/add', formdata).subscribe();
  }
```

```
 [HttpPost("[action]")]
 [Authorize(Policy = "Adminstrator")]
 public async Task Add()
{
            IFormFile file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["photo"];

            string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "images");
            string uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);

            Product product = new Product
            {
                Name = HttpContext.Request.Form["name"],
                Description = HttpContext.Request.Form["description"],
                Price = Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Request.Form["price"]),
                PhotoName = uniqueFileName,
                IsInStock = Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Request.Form["isInStock"])
            };

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                _context.Products.Add(product);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
}
```

Now i want the reverse thing to send the same datas with image from webapi to angular front end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i want the reverse thing to send the same data with image from webapi to angular front end

If you'd like to pass data of product with image to your Angular front end app for displaying product information, you can include image path info in data instead of directly passing image file, like below.

*In API controller action*

```
var product = new Product
{
    name = "product_name_here",
    description = "blabla..",

    //...
    //other properties
    //...

    //pass path info of product image
    photo = "images/filename.png"
};
```

*In Angular front end*

```
this.getProduct().subscribe(p => {
  this.product = p;
  this.product.photo = 'https://<api_server_address>/' + this.product.photo;
});
```

*function getProduct*

```
getProduct(): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<Product>('https://<api_server_address>/getproduct');
}
```

*In Startup.cs*

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images")),
    RequestPath = "/images"
});
```

Comment: Thank you very  much for your answer.

Comment: Lets say i want to use that path in angular front end like this  <img [src]="link of the photo"> . How to catch the error  if the file is not found in the images folder in web api  in this case i want to show a default image which is my angular front end

Answer (score 0):

With Dotnet Core API it is really simple to return json objects from an API endpoint right out the box.

You can create an object to send back via the request.

```
    public class ReturnObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string PhotoName { get; set; }
        public bool IsInStock { get; set; }
    }
```

And then the controller endpoint

```
    [HttpPost("[action]/{id}")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Adminstrator")]
    public async Task<ReturnObject> Get(string id)
    {

        // Gather your data to return

        return new ReturnObject()
        {
            Name = "Name",
            Description = "Description",
            Price = 299,
            PhotoName = "Photo Name",
            IsInStock = false
        };
    }
```

The return object defines the structure of the data to return, and from your angular app, you can call `{URL}/get/myId` for example.

Comment: how to send the photo  with the datas